# Bad scroll performance — Famo.us/Angular scrollview

Tags: famo.us, famous-angular

I'm experiencing bad scroll performance on mobile devices with Famo.us `scrollview`. I'm using `Famo.us/Angular`. Here's the code used:

```
<fa-app>
    <fa-scroll-view fa-pipe-from="eventHandler">
        <fa-view ng-repeat="item in items" class="item">

            <fa-surface fa-pipe-to="eventHandler" fa-background-color="'#FA5C4F'" fa-size="[undefined, true]">
                <img ng-src="{{ item.src }}" />
            </fa-surface>

        </fa-view>
    </fa-scroll-view>
</fa-app>
```

`scrollview` options are set to default. Some of the Famo.us demo videos show utterly smooth scroll. However, I'm unable to translate that into practice. Since, I have not modified any `scrollview` options and working off a barebone template, I wonder what's causing this.

Comment: whats the quality/size of the images? If they are really high quality it might slow them down just because of the loading time of the images. I'm sadly taking shots in the dark. I use famo.us vanilla. I've used a large feed of images in vanilla without any trouble. It was on mobile sizes so I didn't have any Giant images.

Comment: @aintnorest I'm seeing bad performance even with 20 images of 512x512 size. I came across a demo in a tutorial posted on IBM blog that shows similar performance issue (especially on Android). The demo does not use any images at all. http://famous.mybluemix.net/app4/?cm_mmc=dw-_-bluemix-_-wa-famous-_-article

Comment: which version of famous/famous-angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Even Javascript code is very slow with no content! Check out this [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwkflvyEbtE).
The performance is extremely bad and I think you need to think twice before using it.